# error update bibliography Unicode char ″ (U+2033) (inputenc)

Tags: bibliographies, chemformula

I have a severe problem with Latex :). Right now I am writing my thesis (Texmaker), and since yesterday an unknown problem occured. If I wanna actualize the bibliography, I get the following error:

```
File:
C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\chemformula\chemformula.sty
Message:
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ″ (U+2033)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

The file is not compiling anymore. It happens, when I add a certain literature source. For other literature sources there is no problem. 
Since I am a very beginner with Latex, I have absolutely no idea where to start. 
Before that, compiling did work fine. I am irritated, since the error message mentiones the chemformula package, which I didn't change at all and worked also fine before. Where is the connection between Bibtex and the chemformula package???

Has anyone an idea of it? I'd appreciate any help :)

Sorry, I am so confused, I have no idea, what I should write in a working example :(

Comment: Without seeing the source it is pretty hard to help you, so please post a MWE.

Comment: it seems unlikely to be related to chemformula, the format for the error message you show does not look like tex's layout I suspect you are showing a "filtered" view from some editor, can you show that section of the log file with the actual context and error message a slogged by latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+2033 is a double prime, it is probably better to avoid having such characters in your bib file but you can declare it to latex with

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2033}{''}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was the bibfile, with this unknown character...problem solved, but I am still wondering, why the chemformula package is mentioned...

Comment: @MariusKnapp as I put in a comment under the question I suspect that is just some other unrelated part of the log file, but without seeing the log, or the input only you have the information:-)